# [Classpath]: Could not load AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, db2

Hello i have this error  [Classpath]: Could not load AnnotationConfiguration while i'm trying to use hibernate tool to generate table to/from database that i use. I create a simple maven project just to test the connection. NOTE: On Database Development Perspective - I create a Database Connection that can send Pings to my db

pom.xml

```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.o7planning</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateGenerateEntities</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HibernateGenerateEntities</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
   
        
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:db2:URL:sslConnection=true;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect
        </property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image: Hibernate Config]

I tried to add:  `<scope>provided</scope>` for hibernate core/ validator also in hibernate.cfg.xml i add SYSTEM. Thanks.

Full error trace:

```
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.buildConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension$5.execute(HibernateExtension.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.execute(HibernateExtension.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.buildWith(HibernateExtension.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.common.HibernateExtension.build(HibernateExtension.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.build(ConsoleConfiguration.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(ConsoleConfigurationWorkbenchAdapter.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: C:\DIALOG\server\workspaces\server-ngg\CommonHibernate\HibernateGenerateEntities\src\main\java\hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2165)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractConfigurationFacade.configure(AbstractConfigurationFacade.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.loadConfigurationXML(ConfigurationFactory.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.configureStandardConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConfigurationFactory.buildConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:145)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: class org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to class org.dom4j.DocumentFactory (org.dom4j.DocumentFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$2$1 @7ab066a5; org.dom4j.DocumentFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @490b38f7) Nested exception: class org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to class org.dom4j.DocumentFactory (org.dom4j.DocumentFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$2$1 @7ab066a5; org.dom4j.DocumentFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @490b38f7)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
    ... 22 more
```